# Hide UIButton after click in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I need to hide UIButton just after it clicked using RxSwift. I'm not getting any way to do this. Need help here!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the whole weak self dance, then:

```
button.rx.tap
    .map { true }
    .bind(to: button.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If there is something that should cause the button to become visible again, that should be merged into this code. It's best if there is only one binding to a particular observer.